# AAD connect provisioning credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, credentials, gmsa

How can I find the credentials for this?

[image]

Please see image below.

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to connect using GMSA**

First install **ACTIVE DIRECTORY DOMAIN SERVICES** and create service account for windows server using the below powershell.

Before executing the powershell script, kindly create one Security name **GMSA-Test**

> PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword is **Security Group Name**

```
    Import-module ActiveDirectory
    Add-KdsRootKey -EffectiveTime ((get-date).addhours(-10))
    
New-ADServiceAccount <youraccountname> -DNSHostName ITFarm1.contoso.com -PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword <GMSA-Test> -KerberosEncryptionType RC4, AES128, AES256 -ServicePrincipalNames http/ITFarm1.contoso.com/contoso.com, http/ITFarm1.contoso.com/contoso, http/ITFarm1/contoso.com, http/ITFarm1/contoso
  get-ADServiceAccount GMSAtest
```

[image]

**Install ADServiceAccount  using powershellon AAD Connect Server**

```
Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity <youraccountname>
```

successfully created service account after ran the powershell commands.

[image]

Configure AAD connect with your **Service Account**.

Service Account Name: **your domain\GMSAtest$**
Password:  **PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword**

[image]

Reference: [Using Azure AD Connect with a gMSA - The things that are better left unspoken (dirteam.com)](https://dirteam.com/sander/2017/12/28/using-azure-ad-connect-with-a-gmsa/)